# Time series plotting issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, timeserieschart

I'm having a problem plotting time series using matplotlib.pyplot. This is my DataFrame:

```
    saledate    MA
0   2007-09-30  441854
1   2007-12-31  441854
2   2008-03-31  441854
3   2008-06-30  441854
4   2008-09-30  451583
```

The Dtypes:

```
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   saledate  347 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   MA        347 non-null    int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
```

I used the code below to plot the chart, however, it's not like what I expect.

```
plt.plot(df['saledate'], df['MA'])
plt.show()
```

This is the output from my code: [The output from the blockcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3CX6.png)

I also tried changing the index to the 'saledate', then changed the dataframe to a series to plot but I still encountered the same problem.

This is an example of my expected output: [Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDAMU.png)

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Please don't use images of code/data, provide a fully reproducible [mre].

Comment: Also, it looks like your data is not sorted, `plt.plot` plots the data points in the provided order. Just sort the data by time: `df = df.sort_values(by='saledate')`. If you have multiple groups, this is a different issue (but also covered in existing questions).